# Subtype and mDNSResponder

Tags: linux, airprint, cups, mdns

I would like to publish my local printer using the instruction from http://praxis.edoceo.com/howto/cups-airprint BUT with mDNSResponder rather then Avahi. This is not about which one is better as Avahi can do this and has it documented, but about how to achieve the same with mDNSResponder

```
myserver.local.
_ipp._tcp _universal._sub._ipp._tcp
631
txtvers=1
qtotal=1
ty=Canon iP4300
note=I am an AirPrint Printer
product=(Canon iP4300)
rp=printers/CannoniP4300
product=(GPL Ghostscript)
pdl=application/pdf,application/postscript,application/vnd.cups-raster,applicati
printer-state=3
URF=none
```

The problem is that I don't know how to specify the subtype (_universal._sub._ipp._tcp) which is required for AirPrint to work.

Answer (score 2):

In C# its done by putting the specifying the subytype in the "**regtype**" parameter of the **Register** method by using the notation below. I would expect that it is the same in linux version of the library.

```
"_ipp._tcp,_universal"
```

HTH
Ben

Comment: this works for me, but where can I find a document to show this usage? Is that a public feature of mDNSResponder, or only a bug? hidden API? or else?